# EF Core 3.1 In Memory database same where conditions return different results

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, in-memory

I have unit tests using EF Core 3.1 In Memory database but the response these two same queries return are different. Is this ef core in memory database bug?

```
var offers0 = await _offerContext.offers
        .Where(o => o.State == OfferState.Active &&
               o.Pricing.PricePerUnit.Currency == "USD" &&
               o.GameItem.Item.Id == itemId).ToListAsync();

var offers1 = await _offerContext.offers
        .Where(o => o.State == OfferState.Active &&
               o.GameItem.Item.Id == itemId &&
               o.Pricing.PricePerUnit.Currency == "USD").ToListAsync();
```

As you see I changed the position of this where condition `o.GameItem.Item.Id == itemId` and it returns different results.

These are my tests results:

`offers0` returns empty list,

`offers1` returns list with 5 elements

Comment: Just to be sure. Are you executing these queries one after another? Without any code in between?

Comment: Yes and I tried to switch their order but still the results were same

Comment: Is it possible for this one `OfferState.Active` to change between queries?

Comment: No, it is enum value

Comment: One last thing. Could you try with adding `.AsNoTracking()` to both queries and later switching it with `AsTracking()`? Also what is your question?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: What's the type of the `itemId`?

Comment: itemId is string

Comment: @DeivydasVoroneckis Can you please attach a logger to the DbContext to check the generated SQL queries for each Linq2Entities statement?

Comment: Also see if switching to `ToList()` fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with the boolean conditions being converted pretty randomly to SQL.
Trying adding a ton of parenthesis around each subconditions.

For example, avoid :

```
o.Pricing.PricePerUnit.Currency == "USD" 
&& o.GameItem.Item.Id == itemId
```

Instead, try :

```
((o.Pricing.PricePerUnit.Currency == "USD")
&& (o.GameItem.Item.Id == itemId))
```

It's especially important with the || (OR) operator. Its precedence evaluation is pretty bad.

Extra tip : Just in case (I don't know if it would help) I've noticed dodgy behaviours with Guids or nullable Guids. Try `o.GameItem.Item.Id.ToString() == itemId.ToString()` where applies